# Are Chrome file system API not supercookies? Why are people not worried about them?

Tags: privacy, web-browser, cookies, chrome, user-tracking

Chrome has a [file system API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem) that seems to persist through normal clearing of the cache, etc.

(In fact, [I'm not sure if there's *any* built-in way to clear this data globally](https://superuser.com/questions/1285544/clear-chrome-file-system-data-for-all-sites).)

Isn't this a security issue? Why is this allowed, and why does no one seem to be worried about it?

I seem to recall that storage mechanisms that aren't easy to clear have always caused lots of security concerns, and I'm baffled at why this one seems to have flown under the radar.

Is there something about it that makes it less of an issue than usual?

Comment: I've answered about the implications below, but I'd consider supercookies to be a privacy/usability issue that is *not* a security issue.  No privilege boundary is crossed by them, and I'd only consider it a security problem if they were not working in accordance with the spec.

Comment: @David: Ah, thanks; you should add that to your answer -- it's a great point!

Comment: Tools like CCleaner can be helpful.

Comment: The "file system API" you linked here only seems to work when the user drag-and-drops a real folder from their PC onto the page. I don't see how you could possibly expect that to be used as a supercookie, since the webpage needs active user intervention in order to access it.

Comment: @Ajedi32: I'm not sure where you got that idea but it most definitely works on my computer without me dragging or dropping anything.

Comment: @Mehrdad The page you linked: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API#Getting_access_to_a_file_system There are two methods listed there, and both require the user to drag and drop a file/directory. I see now though that there does seem to be [a Chrome-specific method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/requestFileSystem) that gives you access to persistent local storage using that API. I assume that must be the part you're referring to.

Comment: @Ajedi32: Yeah, I meant the Chrome-specific method, thanks. I'll update the link.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use persistent storage, the application must request quota, which [results in a prompt to the user](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-requesting-quota).  It could obviously be used as a supercookie at that point, but given that the user has been prompted, it seems to be a less concerning avenue than other areas.  (Also, being Chrome specific would likely make it less targeted than other supercookie techniques.)

Temporary storage is not prompted, but the browser can clear it at any time.  I'm not sure when this occurs, but I believe it should occur if you clear all local data.

I'm not aware of any specific security concerns related to this API, since it provides a sandboxed filesystem to each origin.  (It cannot read/write arbitrary data from other applications or locations on the user's computer.)

I consider this a privacy issue more so than a security issue -- in my mind, if the API is working as intended and does not leak/reveal data that was not in the original design, then it's a privacy decision that was made by the spec designers.  (Obviously, many users are unhappy by many privacy decisions that have been made -- I'm not saying it's desirable.)  It becomes a security concern when a privilege boundary is crossed or you can use it to reveal information that the designers did not intend.  (Such as the implications of canvas fingerprinting.)

Comment: That's only for `PERSISTENT` though. The `TEMPORARY` one (despite the name) seems to stick around and doesn't get cleared with everything else either.

Comment: @Mehrdad - I believe under "Clear Browsing Data" -> "Advanced" -> "Hosted app data" will do it. Alternatively its possible via the developer tools.

Comment: @Hector: Nope, I just tried it, it doesn't do it.

Comment: is the data stored in OS's temp folder? The OS should clear at some point, maybe reboot or disk cleanup...